# JUnit / Hamcrest - org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is() is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

The method `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is()` deprecated.
The [doc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#is(java.lang.Class)) says to use - `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.isA()` instead.

But `isA()` seems to serve a different case all together.

Ok. What ever, coming to my problem. Earlier I was using `is()` as below

```
// might be i should not be using it like this, but it works.
assertThat(actualRes, is(true));
```

Now i can not use that same with `isA()`. It throws compilation error 
    not applicable for arguments(boolean)

I understand what `isA()` does. What I want to know is, given `is()`  is deprecated, what should I be using as replacement for `assertThat(actualRes, is(true))`?

Answer (score 6):

The deprecated form of `CoreMatchers.is()` is [this one](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#is(java.lang.Class)):

> is(java.lang.Class type)
>
> Deprecated. use isA(Class type) instead.

So, for this `isA` is the correct alternative but the form of `CoreMatchers.is()` which you are using in this assertion: `assertThat(actualRes, is(true));` is [this one](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#is(T)) ...

> is(T value)
>
> A shortcut to the frequently used is(equalTo(x)).

... which is **not** deprecated.

Here's some code which might clarify matters:

```
boolean actualRes = true;

// this passes because the *value of* actualRes is true
assertThat(actualRes, CoreMatchers.is(true));

// this matcher is deprecated but the assertion still passes because the *type of* actualRes is a Boolean
assertThat(actualRes, CoreMatchers.is(Boolean.class));

// this passes because the *type of* actualRes is a Boolean
assertThat(actualRes, CoreMatchers.isA(Boolean.class));
```

Comment: appreciate your answer. But sadly, http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is(java.lang.Class) says it is also depreciated. ?  Am just moments away from going mad. Any further suggestions can restore me. :-)

Comment: @samshers I have updated my answer, in brief; this method: `is(java.lang.Class<T> type)` **is** deprecated but you are **not** using that method in this assertion: `assertThat(actualRes, Matchers.is(true));`

Comment: gr8, got it. tx.